# How to lazy load components on viewport in Angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

My `app-component`  has quite a number of child components that do not all come into the viewport at once. I would not like to load all the components at once since most of the times the users may not need to scroll to the bottom. So is there a way to lazy load the child components only if they are into the viewport/close to the viewport?
Here's my code of app-component template:

```
<!--Header-area-->
<header class="relative header-area" id="home">
  <div class="header-bg header-bg-color">
    <div class="header-bg-image header-bg-image1 home-parallax"></div>
  </div>

  <!--Mainmenu-area-->
  <app-mainmenu></app-mainmenu>
  <!--Mainmenu-area/-->

  <div class="header-scroll-btton smoth">
    <a href="#about"><span class="ti-arrow-down"></span></a>
  </div>

</header>
<!--Header-area/-->

<!--About-area-->
<app-about></app-about>
<!--About-area/-->

<!--Facilities-area-->
<app-facilities></app-facilities>
<!--Facilities-area/-->

<!--Staff-area-->
<app-staff></app-staff>
<!--Staff-area/-->

<!--Administration-area/-->
<app-administration></app-administration>
<!--Administration-area/-->

<!--Gallery-Area-->
<app-gallery></app-gallery> //This is very expensive to load
<!--Gallery-Area/-->

<!--News-Area-->
<app-news></app-news>
<!--News-Area/-->

<!--Contact-Area-->
<app-contact></app-contact>
<!--Contact-Area-->

<!--Footer-area-->
<app-footer></app-footer>
<!--Footer-area/-->
```

Comment: Instead of trying to lazy load the components on the page, why don't you try to create a directive which lazy load the images (in the gallery) ;]? Check out these  https://github.com/tjoskar/ng-lazyload-image

Comment: Thanks. Lazy loading the gallery certainly makes the page load faster. However is there a way to lazy load the other components as well? Cuz some of them use some heavy css indeed.